# AppsScripts: Trying to get one form trigger to trigger another form trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

Okay, so the overview here is that I'm trying to setup an application through AppsScripts, Google Sheets and HTML, but I have a form trigger that is not triggering.

I followed one tutorial to setup an HTML form that sends the information through AppsScripts to a Google Sheet. This utilizes a form trigger to send it to the spreadsheet. I also followed another tutorial that helped me setup another script that turns form submissions to Google Sheets into a PDF. This uses another form trigger, to take the content of a row, and turn it into a PDF.

I was able to get the second part of it working with a Google Form, and then worked on setting up the HTML form to Google Sheets. I managed to get it working (where the html form results populate the spreadsheet), but now the PDF Creator script is not triggering. Is Google Sheets simply not setup for this, or is there possibly some sort of configuration that I'm missing? I'm quite new to this, and I've tried to do my homework to understand each part of the code, but I've hit a wall. Much appreciated for any help, or thoughts, even if it's to go a different direction

Here's my code (trigger configuration is listed below):

```
const sheetName = 'Sheet1';
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function initialSetup () {
    const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId());
}

function doPost (e) {
    const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    lock.tryLock(1);

    try {
        const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1vb7K3IXYC-7zf9BHFYUWN-nQleeWVHsaI8V5OUZNWL4");
        const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

        const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
        const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

        const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
            return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
        })

        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

        return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }

    catch (e) {
        return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
    }

    finally {
        lock.releaseLock()
    }
}

function afterFormSubmit(e) {
    const info = e.namedValues;
    createPDF(info)
}


function createPDF(info) {

    const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("docFileID");
    const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("tempFolderID");
    const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("pdfFolderID");
    const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
    const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
    const body = tempDocFile.getBody();

    body.replaceText("{first}", info['First'][0]);
    body.replaceText("{last}", info['Last'][0]);
    tempDocFile.saveAndClose();

    const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(info['First Name'][0] + ' ' + info['Last Name'] 
        [0]);

    tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
}
```

And then my triggers are configured as such:
Function: doPost
Which runs at deployment: Head
Event Source: From spreadsheet
Event type: On Form Submit

Function: afterFormSubmit
Which runs at deployment: Head
Event source: From spreadsheet
Event type: On Form Submit

Comment: I think I could use a block diagram to help me to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `removeFile()` is deprecated:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#expandable-1. You can use `Drive.Files.remove(tempFile.getId())`

Comment: Are you thinking that posting to the doPost() endpoint is going to create the afterFormSubmit Trigger.? Because if you are that is not going to work.  onFormSubmit triggers are only for Google Forms

Comment: Wow, thanks for the speedy response! Ahhh, the onFormSubmit triggers only work with Google Forms? I thought (based on some of the documentation) that it was a bit vague on whether it would or would not work. I was hoping that the doPost() function would trigger the afterFormSubmit()... I suppose I'll try to use a onEdit trigger for now 

Comment: onEdit triggers only fire on user edits and not on edits cause by formulas and other scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably misunderstand but I'm thinking you think that the webapp post to the doPost endpoint is going to fire afterFormSubmit and unfortunately that is not going to work because they are only for google forms.

If  you can explain what e.values is from the doPost submission then we can help you figure out how to call createPDF from the doPost()

```
function initialSetup() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('key', SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId());
}

function doPost(e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(1);

  try {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const hs = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    const nr = sh.getLastRow() + 1;
    const newRow = hs.map(h => h == 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]);
    sh.getRange(nr, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
    //createPDF(newRow);//maybe this will work for you instead of the afterFormSubmit();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nr })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}

function afterFormSubmit(e) {//this is only generated by a google form submission
  const info = e.namedValues;
  createPDF(info)
}

function createPDF(info) {
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("docFileID");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("tempFolderID");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("pdfFolderID");
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{first}", info['First'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{last}", info['Last'][0]);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(info['First Name'][0] + ' ' + info['Last Name'][0]);
  Drive.Files.remove(tempFile.getId());//You can use Drive API to do this
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, of course, why didn't I think about triggering createPDF() within doPost()? e.values should be the content of the form getting submitted I think, do you think I can just add the function of afterFormSubmit() to the end of the try statement within doPost?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Comment: It's working, thanks so much for pointing out the obvious to me!